# Integrate iXGuard to Flutter project

Tags: ios, flutter, dexguard, ixguard

I am trying to integrate iXGuard to my Flutter project. I have downloaded the iXGuard and installed it, but I can't figure out how to configure iXGuard to my project, the documentation is not very clear.

How can I create the ixguard.yml file? I saw that the command is ixguard.yml -o [Obfuscated IPA file name] [Generated IPA file name].

config ixguard.yml -o [After obfuscation IPA] [File name] [Generated IPA file name]

Also for this, the config command is not recognized

Comment: While Guardsquare does not provide answers on SO on our commercial products, we will be happy to help you in the official support channel.